# Int32.TryParse equivalent for String?

Tags: string, f#

I have been doing some homework. The task was to implement **System.Int32.TryParse** to check if an entered value is a number or something random. I was wondering if there is a **built-in** method that checks if something entered is **a letter** and NOT a number. I tried searching google and MSDN in the string type, but with no luck so far. I did write my own implementation, but I was curious.
Tnx

Comment: You can find *regular expressions* useful; `Char.IsDigit(character)` if you want to test a *single character*.

Comment: Char.IsDigit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Does that also work when I have a string a and I want to test a.[0]?

Comment: Yes, you can access individual characters in a string by using array-like syntax https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323829.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to check whether a character is a number is probably to check whether it is in range from `'0'` to `'9'`. This works because of the way characters are encoded - the digits are encoded as a sub-range of the `char` values.

```
let str = "123"
let firstIsNumber = 
  str.[0] >= '0' && str.[0] <= '9'
```

This gives you a bit different behavior than `Char.IsDigit` because `Char.IsDigit` also returns `true` for thigns that are digits in other alphabets, say `႐႑႒႓႔႕႖႗႘႙` I suspect you do not plan to parse those :-).